# Django ORM form for the following sql query

Tags: django

I would like to know how to frame the following to the Django ORM form:

```
SELECT name,mobile_number,COUNT(*) as count, created FROM core_user,core_useractivity  WHERE core_user.id = core_useractivity.user_id GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY count DESC;
```

where name, mobile number are columns in core_user table or USER model, and created is a column in core_useractivity its model is UserActivity . The two tables are joined on user_id. Further I am grouping the rows by user_id displaying the result in Descending order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try annotating the users with the user activity count.

```
from django.db.models import Count
User.objects.annotate(num_activities=Count('useractivity')).order_by('num_activities')
```

This will return a queryset of users, each with an attribute `num_activities`. See the [docs on annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) for more information.